# Userform throws error when using "." or "-" or "backspace"

Tags: vba, excel

Hello my userform in Excel keeps throwing an error whenever I try to input anything that isnt a number i.e. "." or "-" or if I backspace my number to clear the row.

I believe it because I defined the variable that the userform will be assigned to as a long.

This prevents me from inputting negative numbers or decimals without throwing an error.

Any idea's as to how I can allow my userform to accept the Long variable type while still allowing me to enter other characters that aren't directly a number?

To be clear the error occurs while entering the number into the UF not after I action the Userform.

EDIT:

Code for this is quite simple

```
Public LTB As Long

Public Sub LotTextBox_Change()

LTB = LotTextBox.Value

End Sub
```

Error Msg is - Run time error 13 - Mismatch.

Comment: *What error* are you getting?  Please update your question with a full description of the problem, and include the relevant code and the properties for the "problem" textbox

Comment: it's hard to tell without knowing what your doing with the variable. have you tried defining as `variant` instead of `long`

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are facing is because you are trying to store whatever is being typed in the textbox which is a `String` at runtime to a `Long` Variable.

So if you want to type `-123` then the moment you type `-`, you will get an error as you are trying to store a `String` i.e `-` in a `Long` variable.

Try this

```
Public LTB As Long

Private Sub LotTextBox_Change()
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    LTB = Val(LotTextBox.Value)

Whoa:
    'Debug.Print LTB
End Sub
```

What this does is, it tries to store the textbox value to the variable and if it is not of correct datatype, it exits gracefully.